# Drupal 8 filter or token to replace multiple patterns in a block of text

Tags: php, drupal-8

I'm not really sure how to ask this but, I'm trying to see if there is a way to make a D8 filter, or token, that I can use to search through text, and replace parts with something else.
The end results would be the ability to add something like: [amzn 0970810458]' while typing in a body field, and then when viewed, the part in the brackets would be replaced with a link to that ISBN number's book on Amazon.

I was able to make a test code that was able to find the ISBN numbers in a string of text:

```
$source_string = ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [amzn 0970810458] consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris facilisis felis eu turpis ultrices molestie. Donec vel ornare eros. Integer pharetra hendrerit tincidunt. Nunc in magna vitae nibh tempus pulvinar. Cras lacinia nibh ac justo placerat pretium. Mauris volutpat non ligula sit amet tempus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. [amzn 097081044X] Suspendisse tincidunt tristique ante.");

preg_match_all("/\[amzn([^\]]*)\]/", $source_string, $matches);
$isbns = array_unique($matches[1]);
foreach($isbns as $isbn) {
    $last_isbn = $isbn;
            echo $isbn;
}
```

The thing is, that's useless unless I can use something like 'strpos' to take each ISBN number, stick it into a URL, then replace the bracketed parts with the correct links. Then I need to see if it can all work within a Drupal filter.
Maybe I'm trying to make something that isn't possible, so I'm hoping someone here can tell me if I'm nuts or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're nuts. Replacing the bracketed text with a link is actually not difficult with what you have supplied as you can use `preg_replace` to do the replacement instead of something like `strpos` as you describe:

```
$source_string = ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [amzn 0970810458] consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris facilisis felis eu turpis ultrices molestie. Donec vel ornare eros. Integer pharetra hendrerit tincidunt. Nunc in magna vitae nibh tempus pulvinar. Cras lacinia nibh ac justo placerat pretium. Mauris volutpat non ligula sit amet tempus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. [amzn 097081044X] Suspendisse tincidunt tristique ante.");

$result = preg_replace("/\[amzn ([^\]]*)\]/", "<a href='https://www.amazon.com/dp/$1'>$1</a>", $source_string);

echo $result;
```

Looking at some [guides](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/creating-a-custom-filter-in-drupal-8) it shouldn't be too hard to implement a Drupal 8 filter for this.

**Edit:**
If you wanted to define a title as well it could be done like this using your format:

Slug: `[amzn 0970810458 "The Title of This Book"]`

Regex: `preg_replace('/\[amzn ([^\s]+) "(.+?)"\]/', '<a href="https://www.amazon.com/dp/$1">$2</a>', $source_string);`

See https://3v4l.org/U9PHS for full example as above.

There are many different ways of formatting this. The way you've described is fine just note there would need to be some extra code to handle if for example the title of the book contained double quotes.

Comment: That's funny. That article link is the one that got me started with this idea.
I must had done something wrong before because I tried 'preg_replace' and it didn't work. I just used your code and it worked great. Now I somehow need to understand, and make it all work in a filter. Thanks much!

Comment: What if I could take it one step further? Is regex smart enough so that I could add the book title to the replace? Something like: [amzn 0970810458 "The Title of This Book"]. When it does the replace, it would show the book title as the link with the ISB in the URL as before.

Comment: @TomP: Absolutely you can. See my edited post above.

Comment: Thank you so much! That just saved me a ton more research that I just couldn't seem to make work.